# How to pass variables with spaces through URL in :Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am having trouble in passing variables with spaces in them through the urls. 
Now Suppose I have an object

```
class Kiosks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now the "name" entered for kiosk is say "Akash Deshpande" and saved. Now while redirecting to a new page in the views, i am using the "kiosk name " 
i.e.

```
 messages.success(request,"Kiosk edited successfully") 
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/kiosks/'+kiosk.name+'/')
```

The view which caters to this url is as follows:

```
def dashboard(request, kiosk_name):
    kiosk =Kiosks.objects.get(name__iexact = kiosk_name)
    deal_form = DealsForm(kiosk=kiosk)
    code_form = CodeForm()
    unverified_transactions = get_unverified_transactions(kiosk)
    return render(request,'kiosks/dashboard.html',{'kiosk':kiosk, 
                                                   'deal_form' : deal_form,
                                                   'code_form' : code_form,
                                                   'unverified_transactions' : unverified_transactions})
```

The main urls.py simply directs everything with "kiosks" to bellow urls
kiosks urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('kiosks.views',url(r'^(\w+)/$', 'dashboard'),)
```

Now instead of going to this page it is giving an error "Page not found". How do i pass variables which have space in them ?
Is the question clear? 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what does the view entry in urls.py look like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Allow spaces in your regex.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('kiosks.views', url(r'^([\w ]+)/$', 'dashboard'),)
```

And for the love of Pete, use `reverse()`. It will help you catch silly mistakes like this.

Answer (score 4):

yup .. allow spaces in your regex .. something like this works for me ..

```
url(r'^find-interiordesigners/state-(?P<state>.+?)/$',DesignersByCategoryCityState.as_view(),name='findInterior-state'),
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the relevant example i have used to ignore the space in regex, where \s is working to avoid space in the url name

> url(r'^api/product/(?P<product_name>[\w\s]+)/$',ProductDetailApiView.as_view()),